# Incheon – Phnom Penh (from FRU – ALA – ICN – PNH)

Tags: visas, cambodian-citizens

I am planning to fly from Bishkek to Phnom Penh Via Incheon Airport, Seoul, Korea.

I have one question: Do I need Korean Visa during my transit for Incheon – Phnom Penh?

Thank you in advance and I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: You're booked on the same ticket right through right? And you don't intend to leave the airport and enter South Korea?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.